# In React how to decide whether to use componentWillReceiveProps or componentWillMount?

Tags: reactjs

componentWillMount is called once at first render

componentWillReceiveProps is called for subsequent renders

So - if I want to do some action (e.g. initialise some data in a store) when the component is rendered where do I put this code?  - Which depends on a prop passed in from a higher level component.

The problem is I don't know for sure if the prop will be initialised by the time the first render is called. (The prop depends on asynchronous data). So - I can't put the code in componentWillMount. But if I put it in componentWillReceiveProps and then change something higher up the component chain so that the data is fulfilled synchronously now my code in  componentWillReceiveProps is never run. The motivation for this post is that I just did just that and now have to refactor a bunch of components.

It seems the only solution is to put the code in both methods.

There is no lifecycle method which is always called - for the first time and subsequent. But how can you know for sure if your data in top level components will necessarily be available by the time of the first render? Or for that matter necessarily not. Or maybe you can be - but then you change this.

This lifecyle approach seems very fragile to me. Have I missed something? (Most likely).

Comment: If the data needs to be re-fetched every time its rendered, then I think you're right that the lifecycle model doesn't help. You should just fetch that data again on each `render()`, if thats what you're you're trying to achieve. The problem with that, and maybe a fundamental problem with how you're approaching this, is that if you fetch on every render, you're going to re-render after ever fetch. If you're just trying to fetch the data when `props.userID` has changed, then `componentWillReceiveProps` is the correct option.

Comment: Basically you are saying that there are required props for the component. Is it wise to render the component while not all required props are available?

Comment: @zwippie - perhaps I should be using shouldComponentUpdate to check if i have required props? But then again this is not called for the initial render. So I end up with a render() method that usually starts with if props.someprop does not exist render an empty span - or something like that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change state when properties change and first mount on React - Missing function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29397669/change-state-when-properties-change-and-first-mount-on-react-missing-function)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You already have the answer: put the code in both methods. However, I'd suggest to convert the props to state in both methods, and use the state as your single source of truth.

```
componentWillMount () {
  this.checkAndUpdateState(this.props);
}

componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
  this.checkAndUpdateState(nextProps);
}

checkAndUpdateState (props) {
  this.setState({ isLoaded: !!props.yourData });
}
```

Comment: This answers most of the question. Regarding the async problem, modify the design so that the component doesn't mount until the async returns by putting a callback on the request. Then, the props will always be ready for `componentWillMount`.  Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29397669